# Lagrange Multipliers to solve extrema

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, optimization, lagrange-multiplier

I have a problem here that I can't solve it. Can anyone help me out here, please?

> Find extrema of function $f(x,y,z)= x^{2} yz$ over the unit sphere $x^{2}+y^{2}+z^{2} = 1$.

Here is my take on it:
$$\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}\bigtriangledown f & = \:< \frac{\partial f}{\partial x}, \frac{\partial f}{\partial y}, \frac{\partial f}{\partial z}>\\ & =\: < 2xyz, x^{2}z, x^{2} y>
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}$$
$$ \begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}\bigtriangledown g & = \:< \frac{\partial g}{\partial x}, \frac{\partial g}{\partial y}, \frac{\partial g}{\partial z}>\\ & =\: < 2x, 2y, 2z>
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}$$
since there are parallel , so the cross product of them equals 0.
Now, to use the conventional Lagrange Multiplier method, I get :
$$
\bigtriangledown f = \lambda \ast \bigtriangledown g $$
$$\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
\begin{cases}
 &  2xyz= \lambda \ast 2x\\ 
 &  x^{2} z=\lambda \ast 2y \\ 
 &  x^{2} y= \lambda \ast 2z
\end{cases}
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}$$
I can't solve x, y , and z from the system.
Then I am thinking, what if I factor the common factor from both gradient vectors.
$$\begin{aligned} 
\frac{\bigtriangledown f }{x^{2} y z} & = \;<\frac{2}{x},\frac{1}{y},\frac{1}{z}> \\
\frac{\bigtriangledown g }{2} & = \;<x, y, z> \\
\frac{\bigtriangledown f }{x^{2} y z}\times \frac{\bigtriangledown g }{2} & = <\frac{z}{y}-\frac{y}{z},\frac{x}{z}-\frac{2z}{x},\frac{2y}{x}-\frac{x}{y}> \text{Cross Product}
\end{aligned}$$
$$\begin{cases}
 &  \frac{z}{y}-\frac{y}{z}=0 \\ 
 &  \frac{x}{z}-\frac{2z}{x}=0 \\ 
 &  \frac{2y}{x}-\frac{x}{y}=0 
\end{cases}$$
Simplify further:
$$ 
\begin{cases}
 &  \frac{z}{y}=\frac{y}{z} \\ 
 &  \frac{x}{z}=\frac{2z}{x} \\ 
 &  \frac{2y}{x}=\frac{x}{y} 
\end{cases}$$
Assume:
\begin{aligned}
\frac{y}{z} &= a\Rightarrow a = \frac{1}{a}\Rightarrow a^{2}= 1\Rightarrow a = \pm 1 \\
\frac{z}{x} &= b\Rightarrow 2b = \frac{1}{b}\Rightarrow b^{2}= \frac{1}{2}\Rightarrow b = \pm \sqrt{\frac{1}{2}}\\
\frac{y}{x} &= c\Rightarrow 2c = \frac{1}{c}\Rightarrow c^{2}= \frac{1}{2}\Rightarrow c = \pm \sqrt{\frac{1}{2}}\\
\end{aligned}
Then, I have no clue what to do afterwards?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, you should have four equations$$\left\{\begin{array}{l}2xyz=2\lambda x\\x^2z=2\lambda y\\x^2y=2\lambda z\\x^2+y^2+z^2=1.\end{array}\right.\label{a}\tag1$$Suppose that $\lambda=0$. Then \eqref{a} becomes$$\left\{\begin{array}{l}2xyz=0\\x^2z=0\\x^2y=0\\x^2+y^2+z^2=1.\end{array}\right.$$whose solutions are $(\pm1,0,0)$ and all triplets of the form $\left(0,\pm\sqrt{1-z^2},z\right)$.

Now, suppose that $\lambda\ne0$. It follows from the first equation of \eqref{a} that $x=0$ or that $yz=\lambda$. But, in fact, you can't have $x=0$, because then it would follow from the second and the third equations and from the fact that $\lambda\ne0$ that $y=z=0$. But then $x^2+y^2+z^2=0\ne1$.

So, $yz=\lambda$. Besides, it follows from the second and the third equations of \eqref{a} that $x^2(y+z)=2\lambda(y+z)$ and that therefore $x^2=2\lambda$ or that $y+z=0$.

If $x^2=2\lambda$, then the second equation of \eqref{a} and the fact that $\lambda\ne0$ tell us that $y=z$. But $yz=\lambda$, and therefore $y=z=\pm\sqrt\lambda$. But then the fourth equation of \eqref{a} becomes $4\lambda=1$, which means that $\lambda=\frac14$. So, we have four new solutions: $\left(\frac1{\sqrt2},\frac12,\frac12\right)$, $\left(-\frac1{\sqrt2},\frac12,\frac12\right)$, $\left(\frac1{\sqrt2},-\frac12,-\frac12\right)$, and $\left(-\frac1{\sqrt2},-\frac12,-\frac12\right)$.

And if $y+z=0$, that if, if $z=-y$, then the second equation of \eqref{a} becomes $-x^2y=2\lambda y$, and therefore $y=0$ or $x^2=-2\lambda$. But $y=0\implies z(=-y)=0$ and then it follows from the first equation of \eqref{a} and from the fact that $\lambda\ne0$ that $x=0$. But, again, that's impossible. So, $x^2=-2\lambda$ (and so $\lambda<0$). But now $2xyz=2\lambda x\implies yz=\lambda$, and so $y=\sqrt{-\lambda}$ and $z=-\sqrt{-\lambda}$ or $y=-\sqrt{-\lambda}$ and $z=\sqrt{-\lambda}$. It is easy to see that this leads to four new solutions: $\left(\frac1{\sqrt2},\frac12,-\frac12\right)$, $\left(-\frac1{\sqrt2},\frac12,-\frac12\right)$, $\left(\frac1{\sqrt2},-\frac12,\frac12\right)$, and $\left(-\frac1{\sqrt2},-\frac12,\frac12\right)$.

So, the maximum is $\frac18$, which is attained at $\left(\frac1{\sqrt2},\frac12,\frac12\right)$, at $\left(-\frac1{\sqrt2},\frac12,\frac12\right)$, at $\left(\frac1{\sqrt2},-\frac12,-\frac12\right)$, and at $\left(-\frac1{\sqrt2},-\frac12,-\frac12\right)$.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed explanation

Comment: I think that the merit of my answer lies more in the fact of being correct than in the fact of being detailed.

Comment: It is correct, and I am still digesting it slowly. I can not thank you enough for your effort and help. Once I grasp it completely, then I will know more about what to comment on.

Answer (score 1):

Divide $x^2z=2\lambda y$ by $x^2y=2\lambda z$ and get $\color{red}{y=\pm z}$; divide $2xyz=2\lambda x$ by $x^2z=2\lambda y$ and get $\color{red}{x=\pm \sqrt 2z}$. Subb reds in the unit sphere equation and get
$(\pm\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}},\pm\frac12,\pm\frac12)$. So, $f_{max}=\frac18$ at $(\pm\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}},\frac12,\frac12)$ or $(\pm\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}},-\frac12,-\frac12)$ and $f_{min}=-\frac18$ at $(\pm\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}},\frac12,-\frac12)$ or $(\pm\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}},-\frac12,\frac12)$.